# How we can specify that the TRG_2 trigger should be executed before the TRG_1 trigger by recreating the TRG_1 trigger using the execute clause?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created the two trigger, trigger 1 name `TRIGGER_FOLLOWS_TEST_TRG_2` & trigger 2 name `TRIGGER_FOLLOWS_TEST_TRG_1`.

I want the `TRIGGER_FOLLOWS_TEST_TRG_2` trigger to execute before the `TRIGGER_FOLLOWS_TEST_TRG_1` trigger, by recreating the `TRIGGER_FOLLOWS_TEST_TRG_1`trigger .

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRIGGER_FOLLOWS_TEST_TRG_1
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
OF ISSA_STATUS_P, PRB_BEW_CODE
ON PROBE
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE TRIGGER_FOLLOWS_TEST_TRG_2
DECLARE
    V_STATUS VARCHAR2(10);
    V_BEW_CODE VARCHAR2(5);
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
        V_STATUS := :NEW.ISSA_STATUS_P;
        V_BEW_CODE := :NEW.PRB_BEW_CODE;
    ELSE
        V_STATUS := :OLD.ISSA_STATUS_P;
        V_BEW_CODE := :OLD.PRB_BEW_CODE;
    END IF;

    IF (V_STATUS = 'PAF' AND V_BEW_CODE IS NULL) THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20011, 'Error: Status is finalized but assessment code is null');
    END IF;

END TRIGGER_FOLLOWS_TEST_TRG_1;
```

and

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRIGGER_FOLLOWS_TEST_TRG_1
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
OF ISSA_STATUS_P, PRB_BEW_CODE
ON PROBE
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE TRIGGER_FOLLOWS_TEST_TRG_2
DECLARE
    V_STATUS VARCHAR2(10);
    V_BEW_CODE VARCHAR2(5);
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
        V_STATUS := :NEW.ISSA_STATUS_P;
        V_BEW_CODE := :NEW.PRB_BEW_CODE;
    ELSE
        V_STATUS := :OLD.ISSA_STATUS_P;
        V_BEW_CODE := :OLD.PRB_BEW_CODE;
    END IF;

    IF (V_STATUS = 'PAF' AND V_BEW_CODE IS NULL) THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20011, 'Error: Status is finalized but assessment code is null');
    END IF;

END TRIGGER_FOLLOWS_TEST_TRG_1;
```

I have tried this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRIGGER_FOLLOWS_TEST_TRG_1
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
OF ISSA_STATUS_P, PRB_BEW_CODE
ON PROBE
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE TRIGGER_FOLLOWS_TEST_TRG_2
DECLARE
    V_STATUS VARCHAR2(10);
    V_BEW_CODE VARCHAR2(5);
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
        V_STATUS := :NEW.ISSA_STATUS_P;
        V_BEW_CODE := :NEW.PRB_BEW_CODE;
    ELSE
        V_STATUS := :OLD.ISSA_STATUS_P;
        V_BEW_CODE := :OLD.PRB_BEW_CODE;
    END IF;

    IF (V_STATUS = 'PAF' AND V_BEW_CODE IS NULL) THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20011, 'Error: Status is finalized but assessment code is null');
    END IF;

END TRIGGER_FOLLOWS_TEST_TRG_1;
```

When I create this trigger, it shows an error near " EXECUTE".

Comment: Oracle or Postgres?

Comment: I removed the Postgres tag, as this is clearly Oracle syntax

Comment: i want this in postgresql. In oracle i have done.

Comment: In Oracle if you have several triggers with the same timing point then the order of execution is not determined by default. However, you can control execution flow with the [trigger_ordering_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_trigger.htm#GUID-AF9E33F1-64D1-4382-A6A4-EC33C36F237B__CIHDEBEI)

Comment: In your example `TRIGGER_FOLLOWS_TEST_TRG_2` is a procedure rather than a trigger.